# Do the text indexes added to MongoDb in 3.2 remove the need for lucene?

Tags: mongodb, solr, cassandra, lucene

I want to have a website with full text search on some text fields. I could use [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) on top of [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), but my company would like me to use [MongoDb](https://www.mongodb.com/).

I'm looking at using [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) to build the search queries, but I'm told you don't need to do that in MongoDB anymore, it comes with [full text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/).

My question is: **Do the text indexes added to MongoDb in 3.2 remove the need for lucene?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Mongodb $text index has stemming of words. If your field has a $text index, you could search for **cook** work and document with **cooking** will come up.
2. It can also search for partial words from document like you can search **ook** and it will give you documents containing **book**, **cook** etc.
3. One thing which lucene if powerful is of tokenizing words for did you mean kind of autocorrect. So for example edge-n-gram tokenizer in lucene will tokenize following word :

Word : **mongodb**

To following tokens :

mo, on, go, od, db, mon, ong, god, odb, mong, ongo, ngob, godb and so on..

Depending on what minimum character limit you have set for tokenizer.

So now when you search **kongo**, it will check tokens and it will give score to each token. Document having highest score of token will come in result for incorrect spelling autocorrect. Doing this in mongodb is difficult.

4. You can have multiple indexes, analyzer, tokenizers and create custom ones as well in lucene, in mongodb its not there.
5. You can implement custom stopwords and normalize documents directly in lucene, doing thsi in mongodb is significant effort.
6. You can have different indexes in lucene while saving the data and while searching the data which is really powerful.

On a side note, I had a project on mongodb and we wanted to implement all this, it was so much custom code. We switched to elasticsearch and life was sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is much more flexible, as text search is its primary purpose.

Full text index in mongodb is quite limited. E.g. only 1 index per collection, no custom tokenisers, analysers, stop words, limited supported languages, etc. It should be okay for basic search needs, but you need to check if its abilities match your requirements.

The gap is even bigger, if you compare functionality of Solr or ElasticSearch built on top of Lucene. E.g. there is no such thing like [perlocated queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) in mongo.

On the other hand, using buil-in text search significantly simplifies the system and reduces development time and maintenance cost.